# Multiple instances

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm currently working on a small script where I need to update a file on multiple servers, I have a long IP list of my servers and currently I'm using `ncftpput` to add the files to the servers one at a time.

I can't figure out how to start `ncftpput` with the next IP address in my list so that I can have multiple updates running at the same time.

My list is just IP addresses:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
......
until 192.168.0.150
```

What I need is the first `ncftpput` to access the first IP, the second number two IP and so on for the amount of threads I need / system can handle.

Let's say 10 at a time and when the first thread finishes it just takes the next IP NOT taken by any of the other threads.

I hope I made myself clear on my problem and that someone can help me figure this out.

So far I'm doing it this way: (running one at a time)

```
while read ip; do
    ncftpput -c -A -u "$USER" -p "$PASSWD" "$ip" "/usr/local/program/program.conf" < "~/addthisinfo" 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo -e "Here goes my succes test" >>/tmp/text_added
        else
            echo "$ip failed ! please take care of this"
    fi  
done <"$pathtoiplist""/iplist"
```

I have been trying with some of the answers I found around the net but I can't see my way out of this. I keep ending up with a new instance of `ncftpput` or multiple starting from top of my file and not from the next IP address in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put an `&` character at the end of your `ncftpput` command to make it run in background and return control back to the script immediately, like this:

```
ncftpput [...] < "~/addthisinfo" 2>/dev/null &
```

<sub>I omitted the long list of options you had, don't forget to add them back instead of `[...]`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Byte Commander’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/804194/325633#804199), I suggest

```
while read ip
do
    (
    ncftpput -c -A -u "$USER" -p "$PASSWD" "$ip" "/usr/local/program/program.conf" < "~/addthisinfo"
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Here goes my success test" >>/tmp/text_added
        else
            echo "$ip failed ! please take care of this"
    fi
    ) &
done < "$pathtoiplist/iplist" 2>/dev/null
```

Notes:

- This spawns an asynchronous (background) ***subshell***
  for each IP address in your `iplist`. 
  This allows the shell to detect and log
  the failure of any `ncftpput` instance (process).
- You’ve done a good job of quoting your shell variable references
  (e.g., `"$ip"` and `"$pathtoiplist"`). 
  But you should also quote `"$?"`. 
  Strictly speaking, you don’t need to quote simple constant strings
  like `"/usr/local/program/program.conf"`. 
  But it doesn’t hurt.
- I’m not sure whether you really want the `echo`
  for every successful invocation,
  and I especially don’t know why you want to do it with `echo -e`
  (when the message text doesn’t contain any backslashes).
- You might want to send the error (failure) messages to a file. 
  Since the processes are running asynchronously,
  you might want to write separate error files to avoid collisions; e.g.,

  ```
   echo "$ip failed ! please take care of this" > "/tmp/$ip.error"
  ```
- I moved the `2>/dev/null` from the `ncftpput` command to the loop
  (the `done` line) for simplicity. 
  Note that you cannot do this with the `< "~/addthisinfo"`,
  since you need each instance to read the file independently.
- I changed `"$pathtoiplist""/iplist"` to `"$pathtoiplist/iplist"`. 
  This is safe as long as the first character after the variable name
  (`/`, in this case) is one that is not allowed in variable names. 
  I did the same thing with `"/tmp/$ip.error"`, above.